EF Core design time, removing SQLite
I designed a large solution in ASP.NET Core using domain-driven design (DDD) principals, meaning that my solution hierarchy looks something like this:
/Services
  /ServiceA
    /Api
      /ServiceA.Api.csproj
    /Application
      /ServiceA.Application.csproj
    /Domain
      /ServiceA.Domain.csproj
    /Infrastructure
      /ServiceA.Infrastructure.csproj

The API project is the web project, the domain project contains all of the entities, and the Infrastructure project defines the entity type configurations and DbContext for ServiceA.
When I was originally developing this solution I was using SQLite as the database provider. I generate my migrations by running the EF Core commands against the Infrastructure project. In my Infrastructure project, I have a data folder that looks something like this:
Data/
  Config/
    EntityAConfig.cs
    EntityBConfig.cs
    ...
  Context/
    ServiceADbContext.cs
    ServiceADbContextFactory.cs
  Migrations/
    # Migrations stored here
  Repositories/

My API is able to configure and use the correct DbContext depending on the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT which is either set by launchSettings.json for local runs or by Azure App Service environment variables.
My problem is that I require SQL migrations for my Azure deployments. I did some research and while I saw it was possible to modify my DbContext and the factory for it to produce migrations for multiple providers, I ultimately decided to adapt my local environment to utilize a local Microsoft SQL Server and cut out SQLite entirely.
My factory class now looks like this:
internal class ServiceADbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ServiceADbContext> 
{
    public ServiceADbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) 
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ServiceADbContext>();
        var connectionString = args.FirstOrDefault();

        if (connectionString == null) 
        {
            throw new Exception("A connection string must be provided via command-line arguments.");
        }

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ServiceADbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}

With this system, I am passing in the connection string to the local Microsoft SQL Server when running the dotnet ef migrations add command. I am also targeting the correct project and the correct context to generate the migration.
The problem is when I attempt to generate the migration, I get the following error message:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'ServiceADbContext'. The exception 'Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.1.0.1603, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535'. The system cannot find the file specified.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

It seems like something in my codebase is still trying to use SQLite to generate the migration and I have no idea what it could be. I have completely scrapped all code related to SQLite and purged all project dependencies related to it. I have tried removing all the /bin artifacts, rebuilding and cleaning my solution to no success.
My intuition says that whatever is happening is outside of the codebase and has something to do with how my solution/projects were originally developed using SQLite. I am pretty green in this area and don't know which solution or project properties would be causing this. All of the research I turn to online involves "including" SQLite and getting it to work, whereas my issue is trying to move away from it.

I fixed this by adding SQLitePCLRaw.core NuGet package to the project, but I have no idea why this is required for generating an SQL migration.

IMO you should try to use separated migrations project for different provider. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli
